# Node.JS Result is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I have been working through the tutorial at https://bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/#Define_the_Model and have completed it. I am now adding additional models and controllers, however, I am getting an error. I am a little new to Node.JS so any help would be appreciated.

I have 2 controllers, `customers` and `users`, `controllers` was created in the tutorial and users was a copy and paste of it.

in both of them, I have the following `methods`

```
User.create = (newUser) => {
    sql.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", newUser, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log("created user: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newUser });
        console.log("HERE");
        result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newUser });
    });
};
```

and

```
Customer.create = (newCustomer, result) => {
  sql.query("INSERT INTO customers SET ?", newCustomer, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("created customer: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newCustomer });
    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newCustomer });
  });
};
```

When I send post requests using postman, it works fine for customers but for users, I get the following error `ReferenceError: result is not defined`. It outputs the log message `HERE` but I'm unsure why the final line is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass here

```
User.create = (newUser) => {
```

compare both you will get the solution

```
Customer.create = (newCustomer, result) => {
```